# Image is not showing on ion-option

Tags: javascript, arrays, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to add images after the brand names inside ion-option.
I have the codes below but they do not work. Can anyone help me?
Note: No error is displayed, only the images are not displayed!

HTML:

```
    <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Nome da marca</ion-label>

            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="marcasModel" #C (ionChange)="onChangeMarcas(C.value)" multiple="false" cancelText="Cancelar" okText="Concluído">
                <ion-option *ngFor="let marca of marcas" value="{{ marca.id }}">
                    {{ marca.name }} <img src="{{marca.image}}" alt="" width="30px" height="30px">
                </ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
```

Model:

```
this.marcas = [
        { 'id': 1, 'name': 'Fiat', 'image':'http://www.pngmart.com/files/4/Fiat-Logo-PNG-Transparent-Image.png' },
        { 'id': 2, 'name': 'Ford' },
        { 'id': 3, 'name': 'GM Chevrolet' },
        { 'id': 4, 'name': 'Volkswagen' }
    ]
```

Comment: But the name is showing? Is the image URL showing in the HTML of the template?

Comment: Yeah, if i use {{marca.image}} i see the url address, but if i use <img src="{{marca.image}}" the image is not displayed

Comment: Are you receiving any console errors? In your dev console, in Network tab, the image is loaded or at least called?

Comment: Yes its possible here its code https://github.com/MRameez820/Ion-select-with-image